# Issue with Service Fabric Applicaiton Deployment Task in visual studio team studio (VSTS)

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have added a Service Fabric Deployment Task in my Build definition in VSTS as depicted in the image below.
[Build Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z94N.png)

However, I get error "*Access to the path '' is denied* " as shown in the image below when it runs.

[Build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50fLV.png)

I've tried adding a attrib step to remove the read-only attribute but that doesn't seems to make a difference.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You are missing something in your package directory.  The script is calling Get-Content on a directory and that should be a file.  In the .NET Case this would be an ApplicationParamaters directory with some files in it.  It looks like you may be missing that in your Java app.  I have sent the question to the service fabric team as well.

Comment: Thanks Chris.

I am creating folder structure as mentioned in following link.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app/
That doesn't have the ApplicationParameters in it.

Can you/service fabric team confirm how folder structure should look like for deploying Java WAR file using Service Fabric Deployment Task in VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was entries inside ServiceManifest and ApplicaitonManifest xm files. Especially, the ServiceTypeName parameters. It is actually name of the folder containing file. Refer to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maheshkshirsagar/2016/09/10/deploying-java-war-file-to-azure-service-fabric-using-vsts/) to deploy Java WAR file to Service Fabric using VSTS.